# items of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-api

I am facing a problem . When i tried to receive the value I am getting error that `items of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`. How can i solve this?

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject snippet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("items");
String t = snippet.getString("rating");
```

Comment: The error message is attempting to tell you something...

Comment: Consider using Gson instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JSONArray` is an array of `JSONObject`s. Your `items` json node is an array, not an object. Replace

```
JSONObject snippet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("items");
```

with

```
JSONArray snippet = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
```

Then from your snippet array you can get the item object you need

```
JSONObject item = snippet.getJSONObject(0);
```

And from there

```
String t = item.getString("rating");
```

Comment: jsonarray is giving me int . but in screenshot it is saying only rating .

Comment: The JSONArray has n JSON object nodes, in your case 1 (with index 0). This JSONObject has a key for rating.

Answer (score 1):

Just change from getJSONObject a getJSONArray for the items attribute.

```java
JSONArray snippet = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
```

Answer (score 1):

[..] means it should be an JSONArray and {..} means it should be a JSONObject.

Do this:

```
JSONArray snippet = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
```

JSON having a value enclosed within `[]` signifies an array as is a common practice in most programming languages and `{}` as a plain JSON entity. 
Hence,

> when syntax is {}then this is JSONObject
>
> when syntax is [] then this is JSONArray

Comment: We should always explain while giving solution. Good one.

Comment: Thanks for heads up, added.

Comment: Awesome, keep up contributing as same.